# How to Push Stored Procedure Result into Dynamic Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a scenario where I need to execute stored procedure in inline query and store their output into Temp(Temporary) table and then further filters onto that Temp table , depending upon the requirements.

The examples I have seen are like, creating a #Temp table with all columns definitions,
but I don't want to define each and every column for the temporary table, rather dynamically creation as per SP output.

Can anybody guide me how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert results of a Stored Procedure into a Temporary Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using OPENQUERY, but from my own experience i had lots of difficulties with it (permissions, quite a lot of restrictions and etc.)

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM OPENQUERY(linkedserver, 'EXEC dbo.Sproc');
```